# Ember.js history not working after transitionTo

Tags: javascript, ember.js

please see this functioning JSBin: http://jsbin.com/acUm/20

Here is the behavior I am working on. If I type 'Monroe' to filter the list down and then hit the browser back button, I expect Ember to process the route and fire the request for all patients. Instead it appears to do nothing. This is especially confounding since the back button seems to work in other areas.

Perhaps I have set up this transition improperly? Or is this an Ember.js bug?

Comment: UPDATE: http://jsbin.com/acUm/28/edit?html,js,output. Not even the linkTo helper works after searching and loading the '/filtered/:last_name' route. WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you transition to a route, it's a good idea to use the childest route in the hierarchy.

In your case you have this:

```
this.resource('patients', { path: '/' }, function() {
  // this is created for you
  // this.route('index');
  this.route('filtered', { path: '/filtered/:last_name' });
});
```

By default is created a route index for that resource, so you have the `patients.index`.
But your transition goes to `patients` and it isn't the childest.

So to correct this, I have changed your sample to use `PatientsIndex[Controller,Router etc]`, instead of `Patients[Controller,Router etc]`.

Working demo http://jsbin.com/acUm/24/edit

Comment: Well done! Ember is simple if you understand how it wants you to do things :)

Comment: @Marcio Junior is there any other way to solve the problem other than using the index route?