# Routing & rendering issue in Ember JS when using browser backbutton

Tags: ember.js, routes, rendering, browser-history

I'm working on an exercises-application which shows questions to a user, one by one. When the users solves a question, he gets transitioned to the next question. The questions can be different types (e.g. multiple choice, connect matching, etc). Each question has a preferred view used to render it. When a question is anwsered it's property finished is set to true. I observe that property finished from the question in its questionview, and when set to true the view automatically shows the correct answer to the user.

When the user hits the browser backbutton to go back to the previous question, the setup-controller method from the route gets executed, where the current model is set to the previous model. The observer on that model sees that the question is finished and tries to show the correct answer, but the view hasn't changed yet.

So what happens is that a matching-question tries to draw dots and lines on a canvas-element to show the answer, in a multiplechoice view (that doesn't have a canvas...)

I want the backbutton to work, so a user can go back and see what questions he made right and wrong, and to see the solutions.

Clearly, somethings wrong in my flow here, but I can't see what exactly i need to change

This is my code from the router:

```
// Player.EI is my exercise instance, 
// an Ember Exercise class which has questions, holds score, etc... 

Player.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', {path: "/"});
    this.resource('question', {path: "question/:question_id"});
});

Player.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        this.controllerFor('application').loadExerciseData(); //from xml file
    }
});

Player.QuestionRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition){
        if(undefined === Player.EI){
            this.controllerFor('application').loadExerciseData(transition.params.question_id);
            transition.abort();
            return;
        }
    },
    afterModel: function(model, transition){
        Player.EI.setCurrent(model);
    }, 
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        // the dock is a panel at the bottom of the application, 
        // with buttons to submit and navigate

        d = this.controllerFor('dock');
        d.set('currentQuestion', Player.EI.getCurrent());
        d.set('next', Player.EI.getNext());
        d.set('previous', Player.EI.getPrevious());
        d.set('elements', Player.EI.getElements());

        cn = this.controllerFor(model.getController());

        //this causes the views to do DOM-actions, while in the wrong template
        cn.set('content', model); 

        //do init stuff with the question, like play audio
        cn.enter(); 

        //add a reference to the dock in the controller
        cn.set('dock', d);

        //add a reference to the controller in the dock
        d.set('currentQuestionController', cn);
    },
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {

        this.render('stage'); 

        this.render('dock', {
            outlet: 'dock'
        });

        //each question can tell what controller it needs
        cn = this.controllerFor(model.getController(), model);

        //each question can tell what view it needs to display it
        this.render(model.getPreferredTemplate(), {
            into: 'stage',
            outlet: 'question',
            controller: cn,
            content: model
        });

        //Exercise title,...
        this.render("exerciseinfo", {
            into: 'stage',
            outlet: 'exerciseinfo',
            controller: cn,
            content: model
        });
    }, 
    model: function(param, transition){
        return Player.EI.getElement(param.question_id); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Any chance you can post a full JSBin demonstrating the problem?

Comment: It's too complicated, I think i would need an entire day for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.js history not working after transitionTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391654/ember-js-history-not-working-after-transitionto)